# Getting Out of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error in recursive function in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am getting out of memory error while running this recursion algorithm since I am new to programming can someone please help me in finding my mistake as recursion seems to me a bit difficult topic to me.

The purpose of this program is to find out all the subsets with sum less than or equal to given number.

```
package as;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoOfSubsets {

    static int result = 0;
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> set = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String solve(ArrayList<Integer> A, int B) { // A is the given list of numbers and B is the given number to compare the sum.

        int sum = 0;
        int index = 0;
        Collections.sort(A);
        noOfSubsets(A, B, sum, index, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        System.out.println(set);
        return String.valueOf(set.size());
    }

    public static void noOfSubsets(ArrayList<Integer> A, int B, int sum, int index, ArrayList<Integer> subset) {
        if (sum > B || index > A.size())
            return;
        else if (sum <= B && index == A.size()) {
            System.out.println(subset);
            set.add(subset);
            return;
        }

        noOfSubsets(A, B, sum, index + 1, subset);
        ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>(subset);
        s.add(A.get(index));
        noOfSubsets(A, B, sum + A.get(index), index + 1, s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            a.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        String alist = solve(a, b);
        System.out.println(alist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion + stack overflow or out of memory is almost always a runaway/infinite loop. Have you tried printing out and seeing what happens?

Comment: Its printing well for test cases I am passing but when I am submitting this program in a online portal it is failing for some test case which is hidden and giving me this out of memory error

Comment: It'd be helpful to explain what you're trying to do here, and/or remove the commented out code if it's not relevant.

Comment: I see a proper base case (even though the `sum <= B` is redundant, since you're already in the else case of `sum > B`) and every recursive call has an increasing index without increasing the size of A (so it should eventually terminate) and the algorithm runs fine for me with 5, 10 and 15 random numbers for list A. Check your task manager to see if you're hitting your system's RAM limit and try to find the smallest example for which it gives you this error and include it in the question.

Comment: @Pieter12345 can you please try with A : 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 (20 times 10) and B : 100

Comment: You are getting all subsets with a sum below or equal to 100 from a set of 20 10's. Doing the math, that's `npr(20, 10) + ... + npr(20, 1) = 616665` solutions excluding the empty set. The recursion will have a maximum stack size of ~21 calls for this input array, so that's why you're not getting a StackOverflowError. But these 616665 solutions with ~21 deep recursive calls create ~12949965 ArrayList clones. That's ~12MB heap space per byte an ArrayList actually takes. I'm not surprised you're running into an OutOfMemoryError. You can give the JVM more memory or reconsider your problem size.